# Scrapy 'NameError' multiple pipelines

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline, nameerror

In my spider (spider.py) I use Itemloader to populate scraped items and send them to the pipeline through 'yield l.load_item()' command. If I start my spider, it rans into a 'NameError' and I don't know what is wrong.

I would like to handle ProjectItem and ProjectDetails separately in two different pipelines. I did it as described here: [Scrapy, Python: Multiple Item Classes in one pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743469/scrapy-python-multiple-item-classes-in-one-pipeline)

But now this error message arrives:

```
2021-10-07 13:00:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'project_bid': '$67 / hr',
 'project_bid_no': '10',
 'project_short_text': 'We would like to retype a set of different pages.',
 'project_skills1': 'Copy Typing',
 'project_skills2': 'Data Entry',
 'project_skills3': 'Excel',
 'project_skills4': 'PDF',
 'project_skills5': 'Word',
 'project_time_remain': '6',
 'project_title': 'Re-type a set of different pages',
 'project_type': 'fixed',
 'project_url': '/projects/copy-typing/type-set-different-pages-31736942/'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\XXX\pycharmprojects\postscrape\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.p
y", line 858, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "c:\users\XXX\pycharmprojects\postscrape\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py",
line 150, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\XXX\PycharmProjects\postScrape\tutorial\tutorial\pipelines.py", line 14, in pr
ocess_item
    if not isinstance(item, ProjectItem):
NameError: name 'ProjectItem' is not defined
```

Hope you can help and it is clear what´s the issue.

I reduced my code to the following minimal example:

**spider.py**

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import ProjectItem
from tutorial.items import ProjectDetails
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class FreelanceProject(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dobby'
    #allowed_domains = ['https://www.freelancer.com/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.freelancer.com/jobs/']

    # Schritt 1: Projektliste
    def parse(self, response):
        for projects in response.css('div.JobSearchCard-item'):
            l = ItemLoader(item=ProjectItem(), selector=projects)

            # Extraktion des Projektitels
            l.add_css('project_title', 'a.JobSearchCard-primary-heading-link')

            yield l.load_item()

        project_urls = response.css('a.JobSearchCard-primary-heading-link::attr(href)').getall()
        for project in project_urls:
            yield response.follow(('https://www.freelancer.com' + project + '?ngsw-bypass=&w=f'), callback=self.parse_project)

    # Schritt 2: Projektseiten
    def parse_project(self, response):
        m = ItemLoader(item=ProjectDetails(), selector=response)

         # Budget
        m.add_css('project_budget', '.PageProjectViewLogout-header-byLine::text')

        yield m.load_item()
```

**pipelines.py**

```
import sqlite3
from tutorial.items import ProjectItem
from tutorial.items import ProjectDetails

class ProjectlistPipeline(ProjectItem):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if not isinstance(item, ProjectItem):
            return item

            def __init__(self):
                self.con = sqlite3.connect('freelancer.db')
                self.cur = self.con.cursor()
                self.create_table()

            def create_table(self):
                self.cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects(
                project_title TEXT PRIMARY KEY)""")

            def process_item(self, item, spider):
                self.cur.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO projects VALUES(?)""",
                                 (item['project_title']))
                self.con.commit()
            return item

class ProjectPipeline(ProjectDetails):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if not isinstance(item, ProjectDetails):
            return item

            def __init__(self):
                self.con = sqlite3.connect('freelancer.db')
                self.cur = self.con.cursor()
                self.create_table()

            def create_table(self):
                self.cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS project_site(
                project_budget TEXT)""")

            def process_item(self, item, spider):
                self.cur.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO project_site VALUES(?,?,?,?)""",
                                 (item['project_budget'],))
                self.con.commit()
            return item
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

class ProjectItem(scrapy.Item):
    project_title = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, str.strip), output_processor=TakeFirst())


class ProjectDetails(scrapy.Item):
    project_budget = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, str.strip), output_processor=TakeFirst())
```

**settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'tutorial.pipelines.ProjectlistPipeline': 1,
    'tutorial.pipelines.ProjectPipeline': 1,
}
```

Comment: import 'ProjectItem' in 'pyplines.py'

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added 'from items import' for ProjectItem and Projectdetails in the piplines.py file, but the NameError ist still there. Could that be a problem with the interaction of ItemLoader and pipelines?

Comment: Can you please update your post with the new code?. Also try to change in 'pipelines.py' the name classes to 'SomePipeline(object)'.

Comment: Now you can see the updated code. I also added as a pipeline-object the names of the items that the pipeline should handle. Is that what you mean? Error still arises.

Comment: I run your code with in pycharm with scrapy 2.5.0 and it works fine (except KeyError: 'project_title'). I don't get NameError, what IDE and scrapy version are you using?

Comment: Mh ok. I also use pycharm with scrapy 2.5.0 and python 3.9.

Comment: Ok I got it. I had to put the folder for the items.py file in front of "from FOLDER.items import ProjectItem", now it works. Before I was confused about that, because pycharm underlines it red. Sometimes it is so easy. Thanks!