# Scrapy: Use Feed Exports after custom Item Pipeline without custom Feed Exporter class?

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline, scrapy-pipeline

My Spider looks like this:

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'

    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'img_clear.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline': 100,},
        'FEEDS': {
            'feeds/example/tags.csv': {
                'format': 'csv',
                'fields': ["tag_id", "url", "title"],
                'item_export_kwargs': {
                    'include_headers_line': False,
                },
                'item_classes': [ExampleTagItem],
                'overwrite': False
            },
            'feeds/example/galleries.csv': {
                'format': 'csv',
                'fields': ["id", "url", "tag_ids"],
                'item_export_kwargs': {
                    'include_headers_line': False,
                },
                'item_classes': [ExampleGalleryItem],
                'overwrite': False,
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the `img_clear.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline`:

```
class DuplicatesPipeline():
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        if spider.name == "example":
            with open("feeds/example/galleries.csv", "r") as rf:
                csv = rf.readlines()
            self.ids_seen = set([str(line.split(",")[0]) for line in csv])
            
            with open("feeds/example/tags.csv", "r") as rf:
                tags_csv = rf.readlines()
            self.tag_ids_seen = set([str(line.split(",")[0]) for line in tags_csv])

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, ExampleTagItem):
            self.process_example_tag_item(item, spider)    
        elif isinstance(item, ExampleGalleryItem):
            self.process_example_gallery_item(item, spider)

    def process_example_tag_item(self, item, spider):
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        if adapter['tag_id'] in self.tag_ids_seen:
            raise DropItem(f"Duplicate item found: {item!r}")
        else:
            self.tag_ids_seen.add(adapter['tag_id'])
            return item

    def process_example_gallery_item(self, item, spider):
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        if adapter['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem(f"Duplicate item found: {item!r}")
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(adapter['id'])
            return item
```

With the item pipeline activated it will drop some items (logging: `[scrapy.core.scraper] WARNING: Dropped: Duplicate item found: {'tag_id': '4',...`) and return others (logging: `[scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.example.com/10232335/>`) but noting is written to the files.
Somehow the returned items don't seem to reach the feed exports extension. What am I missing?

- When commenting out the `'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'img_clear.pipelines.DuplicatesPipeline': 100,},` in the `custom_settings`, items are saved in the right csv-files.
- Using `scrapy crawl example -o test.csv` will create an empty csv when the pipeline is activated as well. So it seems that the issue is with the pipeline.
- Printing the items right before they should be returned did print correct item information
- The pipeline is derived from the [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the response! I'm not sure if this would actually have fixed it, since the feed was working perfectly with relative paths when the pipeline is deactivated. I might test that anyways some time.

However, I figured out an other mistake in my code that fixed it without changing the paths:
The [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline) state, that the `process_item` function must return an `item object`, return a twisted `Deferred` or raise a `DropItem` exception.
My code was derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32744929/17517452) but I missed the return statements in the lines calling the `process_..._item` functions.

Tbh, I discovered the solution by accident trying to replicate my issue in a less complex spider and wrote up something like this and it worked:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if isinstance(item, ExampleTagItem):
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        if adapter['tag_id'] in self.tag_ids_seen:
            raise DropItem(f"Duplicate item found: {item!r}")
        else:
            self.tag_ids_seen.add(adapter['tag_id'])
        return item
    elif isinstance(item, ExampleGalleryItem):
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        if adapter['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem(f"Duplicate item found: {item!r}")
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(adapter['id'])
        return item
```

Since I'm very new to coding: Any suggestions how to reduce the repetition in this code? I could use "id" in both Item objects but still would need to differentiate between the two sets so no idea how to do this...